# DAX formula for calculating grouped average from related table

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

I'm trying to calculate the average age for different Groups. See Attached Picture. I have two related tables, and the result of the lower right pivot should match the pivot to its left. I'm fairly New to Power pivot and DAX-formula and I just can't seem to find a solution. Anyone?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaNIE.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might be missing is the `RELATED` function. Try something like this:

```
test = AVERAGEX(Table2, RELATED(Table1[Age]))
```